# Button from mainActivity opens a fragment in a second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i want to push a button in my mainactivity that will start an intent for a new activity with a fragment.
I wrote a main_activity.xml with the button for the MainActivity and a second_activity.xml with a fragment. When I click on the button the second Activity will crash because of the fragment in the xml. 
I already added a flag but it does not help.
The idea of the app is to get a googlemap in this second activity by pushing a button in the main activity.

I hope you can help me :/

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mButton;

    private static final String TAG = Thread.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "+++++ onCreate() +++++");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "+++++ onClick() +++++");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubMain.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "+++++ onStart() +++++");
        super.onStart();

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "+++++ onPause() +++++");
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

SubActivity:

```
public class SubMain extends MainActivity {

    private static final String TAG = SubMain.class.getSimpleName();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "+++++ onCreate().SubMain +++++");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.submain);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mapButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Map" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

submain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
11-13 14:48:24.395: D/Thread(30503): +++++ onCreate() +++++
11-13 14:48:24.465: D/Thread(30503): +++++ onStart() +++++
11-13 14:48:24.475: D/Thread(30503): +++++ run() +++++
11-13 14:48:24.480: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:24.980: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:25.485: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:25.985: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:26.485: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:26.985: D/Thread(30503): Thread is running
11-13 14:48:27.240: D/Thread(30503): +++++ onClick() +++++
11-13 14:48:27.270: D/Thread(30503): +++++ onPause() +++++
11-13 14:48:27.305: D/SubMain(30503): +++++ onCreate().SubMain +++++
11-13 14:48:27.305: D/Thread(30503): +++++ onCreate() +++++
11-13 14:48:27.320: D/AndroidRuntime(30503): Shutting down VM
11-13 14:48:27.320: W/dalvikvm(30503): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41da92a0)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thread/com.example.thread.SubMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at com.example.thread.SubMain.onCreate(SubMain.java:13)
11-13 14:48:27.345: E/AndroidRuntime(30503):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
```

Comment: are you following the tutorial to implement a map fragment ?

Comment: yes. I already made a app with only one  activity and one main.xml with a mapfragment for the googlemap and it works.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:
I got the wrong line for the meta-data in the android manifest... a realy stupid mistake. >.<

Bevor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thread"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thread.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thread.SubMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyCpP0eOduM6JF6w8i7xybZgIiZopG4tOVI" /> <!-- wrong line! -->
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thread"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thread.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thread.SubMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```